# Does Norton Antivirus 11 for Mac OS X pull signature updates as deltas?

Tags: mac-osx, anti-virus, symantec

I manage a Mac OS X (Leopard), laptop that has Norton Antivirus 11 installed.  Whenever LiveUpdate executes, it proceeds to pull down a sig database of approx. 30 MB.  Does anyone know why the updates aren't smaller ?  I would've expected that Symantec downloads deltas of the databases.  It is a concern as the user is a mobile user and does not always have high speed access.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your LiveUpdate is broken. It is supposed to only give you "MicroDefinitions," also called "microdefs," which are updates to your existing definitions database (deltas).

There is a Symantec whitepaper (broken link) explaining this process (it references Windows, but LiveUpdate for Mac operates the same way).

Try installing the lastest updates manually from the [NAV Definition Site](http://www.symantec.com/business/security_response/definitions/download/detail.jsp?gid=nmc), then run LiveUpdate again to see if it works this time.

Comment: Thanks AdamB.  I will perform the manual update.  There's nothing worse than a false sense of security!